# Make Section Tabs expand the entire row

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation

I'm working with Foundation4's Sections now. It is a very nice component, but I wish to do some customization. I don't really know SASS. I notice in the documentation, we can customize by using this line of code:

```
.section-auto-sample-custom {
  @include section-container($section-type:tabs);
  & > section { @include section($section-type:tabs, $title-selector:".title-sample", $content-selector:".content-sample", $title-padding: 10px 50px, $title-color:#000, $title-bg:pink, $title-bg-hover:darken(pink,5%), $title-bg-active: #fff, $title-color-active: darken(pink,10%)); }
}
```

Is this Mixin? Do I have to save it to a .sass file and precompile it or do I just drop it to my regular css file?

Even if I understand this, another question comes ahead: how can I adjust the width of the title tabs to make them auto-adjust with the width of the content? For example, if I have three tabs, they should be on top and have equal width that sum up to be the width of their tab content.

Is there any simple way to do it? Do I need to use JavaScript?

Comment: If you understand that this is Sass code, why didn't you start by looking at the Sass documentation?

Comment: Ehh...well, I just very much need to know if I have to precompile the file that contains this line of code..

Comment: Why would you think you *wouldn't* need to?  Browsers do not support Sass natively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a little snippet of jQuery to do this.

```
$('.section-container .title').width(100/$('.section-container .title').size() + '%');
```